# How to retrieve Image URL in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to retrieve image URL from firebase realtime database.

The following error appears on the screen.

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/trackkit-a5cf3.appspot.com/o/Aborbent%20Gauze.jpeg?alt=media&token=ab1de5ec-bd0b-4abb-9ad6-92a0a79776e5

[image]

[image]

I am able to retrieve 'Item', 'Quantity' etc. But I am unable to display the Image.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final database = FirebaseDatabase(
    databaseURL:
    "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app")
    .reference()
    .child('NTU')
    .child(widget.referenceName);
```

.
.
.
.

```
                           return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: lists.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            void onAdd() {
                              final newItem = lists[index];
                              newItem["Quantity"] = newItem["Quantity"] + 1;
                              final item =
                              Map<String, dynamic>.from(newItem);
                              database
                                  .child(lists[index]["referenceName"])
                                  .update(item);
                            }

                            void onSubtract() {
                              final newItem = lists[index];
                              if (newItem["Quantity"] == 0) return;
                              newItem["Quantity"] = newItem["Quantity"] - 1;
                              final item =
                              Map<String, dynamic>.from(newItem);
                              database
                                  .child(lists[index]["referenceName"])
                                  .update(item);
                            }

                            void onDelete() {
                              database
                                  .child(lists[index]["referenceName"])
                                  .remove();
                            }

                            return _buildItem(
                              lists[index]["Image"].,
                              lists[index]["Item"].toString(),
                              lists[index]["Quantity"],
                              lists[index]["Expiry Date"],
                              onAdd,
                              onSubtract,
                              onDelete,
                            );
                          },
                        );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please provide the code on how you are displaying the image!

Comment: @AloysiusSamuel The code has been provided

Comment: unable to load asset means you use .`Image.network(yoururl)` instead of `assetimage()` widget